# Issue with a python lab assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to do standard deviation for my computer science class and at the moment I've got it all working except the output portions.  I can get DEV/DEV1 to output but when I go to output sd1 using the same method it breaks and spits out 0s even though the function im using to do SD1 is putting out the right numbers I need.

What did I do wrong?

```
n=20
import math
def main():
    #Listdec
    x=[0]*n
    dev=[0.0]*n
    dev1=[0.0]*n
    sd1=[0]*n
    #filedec
    infile=open("lab4.txt","r")
    outfile=open("lab4.out","w")
    #vardec
    sumx=0.0
    std=0.0
    xbar=0.0
    dev2=0.0
    sd2=0.0
    #callfunction
    sumx=loadrec(infile,x)
    sd2=standard1
    #compute average
    xbar=sumx/n
    #call deviation function
    dev2=deviation(x,dev,dev1,xbar)
    #compute standard deviation
    std=math.sqrt(dev2/n)
    #function standard
    standard1(x,xbar,std,sd1)
    #sd2=standard(dev1,sd1,std)
    #calloutdata
    outdata(outfile,x,dev,dev1,sd1)
    print("SUM=",sumx)
    print("AVG=",xbar)
    print("STD=",std)
    print("SD2=",sd2)
    #closefile
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    dummy=input("Press enter to continue") #you know what this is by now 
    #functions
def loadrec(file,a):
    #local var
    k=0
    s=0
    while(k<n):
        #reads first line of data
        templist=file.readline().strip('\n').split(',')
        a[k]=int(templist[0])
        s=s+a[k]
        k=k+1
    return(s)
def standard1(a,b,c,d):
    #a=student score b=avg c=standard deviation
    k=0
    s=0
    while(k<n):
        s=(a[k]-b)/c
        print(s)
        k=k+1
    return(k)

def deviation(a,b,c,d):
    #a=x b=dev c=dev1 d=xbar
    #local var
    k=0
    s=0
    while(k<n):
        b[k]=d-a[k]
        c[k]=b[k]*b[k]
        s=s+c[k]
        k=k+1
    return(s)
def outdata(file,a,b,c,d):
    #localvar
    #file=outfile a=x b=dev c=dev1 d=sd1
    k=0
    #shoves the results to the screen
    print("Scores","   ","DEV","   ","DEV1","   ","SD1","\n")
    while (k<n):
        print((str(a[k])+str("   ")+str(b[k])+("   ")+str(c[k])+str("   ")+str(d[k])))
        file.write(str(a[k])+"  "+str(b[k])+"  "+str(c[k])+str("\n"))
        k=k+1

main()
```

Data file contents are just this:

```
75
90
80
85
76
70
68
84
92
80
50
60
73
89
100
40
75
76
94
86
```

The output I'm expecting will print out just fine except sd1. But when I print the results from the sd1 function, it does it with no issues whatsoever but I need it to be put into the SD1 column.

How can I get it into the column that I have set up so far?  Once I figure that out I can figure out the outdata part.

Comment: You call the `standard1` function, but you're not assigning the result of it anywhere. Maybe you want `sd1 = standard1(...)`

Comment: @slothrop When I plug that in it breaks and gives me int is not subscriptable :/  I keep running into that issue.  I should have put in the main post but this is my first coding class ever so.

Comment: There are many things I don't understand here. Why n=20? Sure your input file happens to have 20 lines but what if the file is changed? Your code will break. Why are you splitting the lines on comma? There are no commas. You don't need to pre-assign values like, for example, *sumx=0.0* Remember, this is Python

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BlueRobin  Thats the problem, it needs all of that to show you what its doing.  I cant trim it.  It lies within standard 1 going to outdata function but both need the rest to show you what its pulling from.

Comment: Why does `standard1` return `k`? Isn't that the loop counter, rather than anything calculated from your data?

Comment: @slothrop I tweaked that, I was messing with it previously to see if I could force values to push to the outdata.  I have since adjusted it, but even with that it sitll spits 0s.  Likely what it was was I was trying to fix it to see if it was counting at one point even cause I have been trying to fix this the entire weekend.

Comment: @DawsonB9822 so right now, that function calculates values of `s` and prints them to the screen, but doesn't save them or return them anywhere. Is it intended to write them into the list `d`?

Comment: @slothrop Thats exactly what I want it to do, I need those S values to go to outdatas D.  I didnt know how to word it right.

Comment: @DawsonB9822 so you could do `d[k] = s` right after you calculate `s`. (If you were rebuilding this from scratch, there are better ways to design it - particularly, we try to make functions *return* their results rather than write them into a shared variable - but adding that line should fix the immediate issue.)

Comment: It did and you are a godsend @slothrop, any chance you can show me why that worked and everything else didn't?  Im new to this and frankly barely understand my professor atm. <3

Comment: @DawsonB9822 so the design of this code (not ideal, but can be made to work) is that the calculation functions are intended to write their results into the lists `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` that are passed around between functions, and finally used by `outdata`. For example, in the function `deviation`, the results were already being written into `b[k]` and `c[k]` but the same wasn't happening with `d[k]`.

Comment: @DawsonB9822 I don't want to disrespect anyone, but if your class is steering you towards writing this kind of code, it might be good to check out some Python tutorials, particularly about structuring code and using functions. The code as written here *can* be made to work in Python, but it feels a little bit like it might have been written in Fortran and converted into Python :) Good luck anyway, sounds like you had a stressful weekend!

Comment: I dont know what was written tbh @slothrop, Im new to this and followed what I was told to learn and didnt learn so.  Any tutorial recommendations?  I want to get into this field but unfortunately lost the professor lottery I guess.

Comment: @DawsonB9822 realpython.com has some good ones - you could try https://realpython.com/courses/python-basics-functions-loops/ and then https://realpython.com/courses/defining-and-calling-functions/ . Take a look and see if you like their style anyway!